# Not able to get the top 5 rows in Azure-Android SDK

Tags: android, azure, kotlin-android-extensions

I have been wondering how can I get less than 50 rows of data with azure. Reason being I only need the top 5 rows of data from the database and display onto the android UI.

However, when I am experimenting `.top()`, the lowest I can go is 40. Anything lower than that, the return JsonArrayQuery will not be regarded as an Array.

```
                val resultQuery:JsonElement = FruitQueryTable.orderBy("name", QueryOrder.Descending).top(40).execute().get()

                val arrayQuery: JsonArray = resultQuery.asJsonArray
                Log.v(
                    "Logger:",
                    "$arrayQuery"
                )

                for(item in arrayQuery){

                    val nameFruit = item.asJsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("name").asString
                    Log.v(
                        "Logger:",
                        "fruitName" : $nameWO"
                    )
                }
```

Based on the [documentation](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/), they did not specify a minimum number of rows.

Is there any solution or fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dated in 2019-early 2020. For now, the

> lowest number of rows that I can retrieve is 40.

Any lower than that, the library will not bother trying to retrieve the rows for you. Hence, I just stick with the default (50) when using the `top()` function